# Is there a tidyverse-way to split one column of character strings into two columns, where sorting depends on specific characters?

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have columns with data for age; e.g 2y:3m equals 2 years and 3 months and 5m = 5 months.

| Age |
| --- |
| 2y:3m |
| 5m |

I wish to separate this column into two: "Years" and "Months", respectively.
I can do this by using the tidyr separate-function with ":" as separator.
However, my problem is that children where age is only reported in months, e.g 5m, the seperation puts 5m into the "Years"-column and NA into the "Months"-column, like this:

| Years | Months |
| --- | --- |
| 2y | 3m |
| 5m | NA |

Does anyone know a handy way to solve this, preferably within the tidyverse packages.

Hope one of you can help!

This is what I tried (after streamlining the notation of years ("years", "year", "ys" and months ("month","months","mths") --> only "y" and "m":

childage1 <- Child_age %>%
separate(eage_clean,c("Years","Months"),sep=":")

One idea is maybe to first put a ":" in front of all values, that only contains months, but I had problems on how to do this...

Comment: Use the `fill` argument i.e. `fill = "left"` i.e. `Child_age %>% separate(Age,c("Years","Months"),sep=":", fill = "left")`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the years and months as numbers, you could extract with regex rather than separating:

```r
df %>% mutate(years  = as.numeric(sub("^.*(\\d+)y.*$", "\\1", Age)),
              months = as.numeric(sub("^.*(\\d+)m.*$", "\\1", Age)))
#>     Age years months
#> 1 2y:3m     2      3
#> 2    5m    NA      5
```

It seems that it may be more useful in this data set to have 0 rather than `NA`, since `"5m"` probably represents 0 years, 5 months, and e.g. `"2y"` probably means 2 years, 0 months. If so, then you may prefer:

```r
df %>% mutate(years = as.numeric(sub("^.*(\\d+)y.*$", "\\1", Age)),
              months = as.numeric(sub("^.*(\\d+)m.*$", "\\1", Age))) %>%
       mutate(across(c(years, months), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))
#>     Age years months
#> 1 2y:3m     2      3
#> 2    5m     0      5
```

Answer (score 0):

With `separate`, if we need to keep it on the 'left' side, use `fill = "left"`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(Child_age, Age,c("Years","Months"),sep=":", fill = "left")
```